# Python: Tokenize text according to phrase length

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

I would like to tokenize text according to the phrase length.

For example, building a function `process_text("Some text to be tokenized please", n = 3)` where n is the phrase length, the result should be like this `["Some text to","be tokenized please"]`.

How can I implement this?

Thank you!

Edit:

Ok maybe I came up with something that works

```
from nltk import ngrams

def process_text(text, n = 1):
    text= list(ngrams(text.split(), n))
    tokenised=[" ".join(i) for i in text]
            
    return tokenised

process_text("Some text to be tokenized please", n = 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way using list comprehensions:

```py
def tokenize(text):
    words = text.split(" ")
    return [' '.join(words[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(words), 3)]

print(tokenize("Some text to be tokenized please"))
# ['Some text to', 'be tokenized please']
```

However, that's not perfect, i.e.

```
>>> tokenize("Some text to be tokenized please")
['Some text to', 'be tokenized please']
>>> tokenize("Some text to be tokenized please ")
['Some text to', 'be tokenized please', '']
>>> tokenize(" Some text to be tokenized please ")
[' Some text', 'to be tokenized', 'please ']
>>> tokenize(" Some text  to be tokenized please ")
[' Some text', ' to be', 'tokenized please ']
>>> tokenize(" Some text  to be   tokenized please ")
[' Some text', ' to be', '  tokenized', 'please ']
```

but you can adapt it to your use case.

Comment: Hi Enzo, thanks for the answer! I edited my post, maybe I came up with a cleaner code using nltk and ngrams. Please share your thoughts

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do this I came up with:

```
def process_text(text, n):
    text = text.split(' ')  # create a list of words the text entered when calling the function
    new_text_1 = ''
    new_text_2 = ''
    x = 0
    for word in text:  # iterate through the words in the provided text
        if x < n:  # if the word is before the split
            new_text_1 = new_text_1 + word + ' '
        elif x < len(text) - 1:  # if the word is after the split but not the last word
            new_text_2 = new_text_2 + word + ' '
        else:  # if this is the last word
            new_text_2 = new_text_2 + word
        x += 1
    return [new_text_1, new_text_2]


print(process_text('Some text to be tokenized please', 3))
```

You can probably improve this a bit, but it gets the job done.